# Firebase download progress observer error Swift 3

Tags: ios, firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

Trying to show firebase download progress, getting error

> "value of type FIRStorageRef has no member observe".

This is the code I got from firebase documents and trying to use.

```
    storage = FIRStorage.storage()

    let storageRef = storage.reference().child("Audio").child(successFileName)
    self.titleLabel.text =  self.successTitlename

    SwiftSpinner.show("Loading...")

    storageRef.downloadURL { url, error in
        if error != nil {

            SwiftSpinner.show("Couldn't load Audio...Tap to dismiss").addTapHandler({
                SwiftSpinner.hide()
            })
       **Getting error here** 
            storageRef.observe(.progress) { snapshot in
 // Download reported progress
    let percentComplete = 100.0 * Double(snapshot.progress!.completedUnitCount)
                    / Double(snapshot.progress!.totalUnitCount)
            }


}
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`downloadURL()` doesn't generate a download task like the other download functions, as per [Download files - Monitor download progress](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/download-files#monitor_download_progress), since it only returns the download URL and not the file's data.

You'll need to use one of the following: `write(toFile:)` or `getData(maxSize:)` and finally `task.observeStatus(.progress)`. The first downloads it to a local file while the latter does so in memory.

Sample from the docs ([full source](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/download-files#full_example)):

```swift
// Create a reference to the file we want to download
let starsRef = storageRef.child("images/stars.jpg")

// Create local filesystem URL
let localURL = URL(string: "path/to/stars.jpg")!

// Start the download (in this case writing to a file)
let downloadTask = storageRef.write(toFile: localURL)

// Download in memory with a maximum allowed size of 10MB
// let downloadTask = storageRef.getData(maxSize: 10 * 1024 * 1024)

downloadTask.observe(.progress) { snapshot in
  // Download reported progress
  let percentComplete = 100.0 * Double(snapshot.progress!.completedUnitCount)
    / Double(snapshot.progress!.totalUnitCount)
  print("Done: \(percentComplete)%")
}

downloadTask.observe(.success) { snapshot in
  // Download completed successfully
  print("Downloaded successfully")
}
```

Comment: thanks for your response, I am streaming audio files from the database. I am not saving the files to local storage, would this work in my situation?

Comment: How are you streaming the audio files ? Library or custom code ? The only ways to get a file from Firebase are the ones described above. Firebase doesn't support streaming protocols (like HLS) or transcoding.

Comment: downloadURL doesn't provide a progress report since it only returns the download URL and not data. You can use `AVPlayerViewController`/`AVAudioPlayer` after to play the audio.

Comment: You can auto-answer your question.